# split userPassword and securityToken

Tags: security, security-token

Let's say we have 3rd party api that should reach salesforce. we want to transfer password and security token in using only one custom http header.
is it possible to split these values?
e.g. MyPleasurePAssworDMuxcrZ0nZHiKHY5eH7pj6q7O
where `MyPleasurePAssworD` is password and the rest is token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be authenticating with a username and password when integrating a remote service. Instead, implement OAuth, using either the [Web Server](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5) flow or the [JWT](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) flow.

Storing and transmitting raw user credentials is inherently less secure and is vulnerable to password and security token changes, while OAuth authentication is not.

The security token is concatenated to the end of the password where raw credentials are used, such as in the [Username-Password](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&type=5) OAuth flow or when performing a [SOAP `login()` call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm#!). I'm not sure what you're referring to vis-a-vis a custom HTTP header.